# can't edit All Item view of a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I found an existing list which is having 300+ items. When I am trying to modify its **All Item view**, its throwing me an error

> > Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 026bcb9e-d0e1-0000-2526-3f63baaaa568

While on error page I checked its URL too, its not giving lists name, instead showing list ID(i guess)

> https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/ViewEdit.aspx?List=%7BD1EB1C50-0B6C-48AF-BCEA-3D00B3B6CFEF%7D&View=%7BC6A2238D-ED92-4C0E-9934-6B2A130C977E%7D&Source=%252Fsites%252Fsitename%252F%255Flayouts%252F15%252Flistedit%252Easpx%253FList%253D%25257BD1EB1C50%25252D0B6C%25252D48AF%25252DBCEA%25252D3D00B3B6CFEF%25257D

Tried to change this ID with list name but it didn't work. Any suggestions !!

Comment: It needs the list id and view id. Can you open the view from list settings -> view section? Which list are you trying to modify the view? Does this issue occur on all lists in the site? You can test it in another list and in another site to narrow down the issue. Check if the issue only occurs on the specific list and only happens on this specific site.

Comment: can't open view even from list setting,......   its a custom list....   only this list is behaving like this, rest lists in this site are working perfectly fine

Comment: Try to creating a new view based on the all item view, and then make it default.

Comment: that actually what I did currently, but my concern is why I am not able to edit this one. There must some reason behind it !!

Comment: You can contact  Office 365 technical support from Support > New Service request to check the logs based on the correlation id to see what is failing.

Comment: Question: has the allitems view more than 5000 items per page? (or had it in the past) if you surpassed the threshold maybe the view got blocked... if you have access to the ULS log one option is to search for the correlation ID in there, it will give you a more detailed entry on the error.